# When does javascript continue loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following code:

```
$(imgHold).attr('src',$(imgHold).data('img-src')).on('load', function() {})
```

Would subsequent code load at the same point or only after the image has fully loaded? Just to be clear I know code can go in the function() of load but am interested to know what comes after.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Well technically it should call the function after image is loaded, however it can vary on browser.

Comment: @RayonDabre So in short what is the answer ?

Comment: In short..Next statement of code will execute immediately...But your callback will be invoked after image is loaded...